# Multiple panel plots with pheatmap

Tags: r, plot, heatmap, pheatmap

I am trying to do multipanel plots one panel being a heatmap using `layout` to place plots. I've been drawing heatmaps with `pheatmap` which provides a very convenient color scheme among other things.

The code for `pheatmap` is available [here](https://github.com/cran/pheatmap/blob/master/R/pheatmap.r).

When I try using `pheatmap` in this way it always plots on a new page. I imagine this is because of its use of the `grid` package? Is there a way I can do this with `pheatmap`?

Example code to produce a heatmap next to a barplot but which doesn't since the heatmap gets plotted on a new page below:

```
xlay=layout( matrix(c(2,2,1),nrow=1) )
layout.show(xlay)
barplot(rnorm(8),horiz=T)
pheatmap(matrix(rnorm(80),nrow=8))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your bar plot in ggplot

```
bar <- ggplot()
```

Assign both the barplots and heatmap to a variable

```
heat <- pheatmap(matrix(rnorm(80),nrow=8))
```

then use `gridExtra` package to make panel plot the heatmap is saved as an object and you can plot it again by assessing the 4th item in the object

```
grid.arrange(bar, heat[[4]], nrow = 1)
```